# Is there any way to turn my laptop into a wireless access point for other devices?

Tags: wireless, networking, sharing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set up ubuntu as wireless accesspoint?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1385/how-to-set-up-ubuntu-as-wireless-accesspoint)

Is there an easy, simple way to setup a wireless network so my laptop (which is connected by a wired connection) can share that connection with my mobile phone and other devices?

Thank you for any answers in advance!

Comment: Duplicate of http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com/questions/1385/how-to-set-up-ubuntu-as-wireless-accesspoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see [How to set up Ubuntu as wireless accesspoint?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1385/how-to-set-up-ubuntu-as-wireless-accesspoint)

Answer (score 2):

1. Right click the Network Manager applet and click "Edit Connections"
2. Go to "Wireless" tab and click "Add"
3. Enter "ICS" in the "Connection name" field
4. Enter "ICS" in the SSID field
5. Change the Mode to "AdHoc"
6. Go to "IPv4 Settings" and select Method "Shared to other computers"
7. Connect to the ICS wireless network

These steps are from memory and might be incomplete. WPA2 security seems not to work.

See http://www.ubuntugeek.com/creating-an-adhoc-host-with-ubuntu.html also.