# Setting up ubuntu as a wireless accesspoint

Tags: wireless

I have an android phone which doesn't connect to ad-hoc networks. I use ad-hoc network to share internet among my pcs. I want to setup my ubuntu laptop as a wireless access point. But I don't want my ubuntu laptop to be a [router as described here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1385/how-to-set-up-ubuntu-as-wireless-accesspoint) as I'll be using suid3 as a http proxy. It should be just a wireless accesspoint which broadcasts it's SSID like a home wireless router. The ubuntu laptop has athros wireless card which requires athk9 driver.

Comment: You should change the question so that it's not obviously a duplicate of the target your linked to (http://askubuntu.com/questions/1385/how-to-set-up-ubuntu-as-wireless-accesspoint).  I've flagged this as a duplicate, but it's clearly not.

Answer (score 2):

I somehow got it working. Here is the tutorial that I did: [Ubuntu netbook as a wireless access-point and router](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1663788)