# How to share internet by creating virtual access point in Ubuntu

Tags: networking, wireless-access-point

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set up ubuntu as wireless accesspoint?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1385/how-to-set-up-ubuntu-as-wireless-accesspoint)

Please are there any software or workaround in Ubuntu by which we can share internet by creating virtual access point like it is been done in windows using virtual router or connectfy.

Comment: Duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/1385/how-to-set-up-ubuntu-as-wireless-accesspoint

Answer (score 0):

If you are running network-manager, just click the notification-icon (networking icon), click create new wireless network, and then enter a name and optionally a password.

*Please comment if this is not what you mean.*