# How to turn my Dell Mini 10v to become a WiFi hot spot?

Tags: 11.04, wireless, sharing, broadband

On natty, how to turn my dell mini 10v to become a WiFi hot spot? i would like to share my usb broadband with my android device and ipad.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure of the hardware associated with a Dell Mini 10v, but take a look at the following: [How to set up Ubuntu as wireless accesspoint?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1385/how-to-set-up-ubuntu-as-wireless-accesspoint)