# How to create a wifi hotspot in Ubuntu Server?

Tags: wireless, server, wireless-access-point

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set up ubuntu as wireless accesspoint?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1385/how-to-set-up-ubuntu-as-wireless-accesspoint)

I have to network interfaces, `eth1` and `wlan0`.

`eth1` is connected to the Internet. I need `wlan0` to serve as a hotspot sharing `eth1`'s Internet connection to anyone connected to `wlan0`. I am running Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessAccessPoint) is a good document which step by step explains how to setup Wireless access point on Ubuntu.